# Error when deploying es6 node.js with babel to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ecmascript-6, babeljs

The program runs totally fine on my local machine but when I deploy to Heroku during production, I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: /tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/gatsby-browser.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (7:10):
  5 | 
  6 | export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
> 7 |   return <Layout {...props} >{element}</Layout>
    |          ^
  8 | }
  9 | 
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at Parser._raise (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:748:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:741:17)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9116:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10569:22)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10150:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10130:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10119:17)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9989:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9963:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/tmp/build_dfc33ed2_/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9926:21) {
  loc: Position { line: 7, column: 9 },
  pos: 209,
  missingPlugin: [ 'jsx', 'flow', 'typescript' ],
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR'
}
```

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xxxxxxx",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.14.4",
    "node": "14.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js --exec babel-node",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build . -s --ignore node_modules",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "heroku_start": "npm run build && node ./build/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix --ignore-path .eslintignore"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.4.1",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring", "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

I added @babel/preset-react to the 'presets' section of the babel config and still got the same error.

PS: I'm not using react or gatsby here. It's a simple node.js API project.

Comment: Ita showing a syntax error in line 7. Have you checked it?

Comment: @Lovekesh There’s no file containing line 7